# Is there a way to adjust the tab setting in guitar pro so that certain frets are not used when converting notes to tab?

Tags: notation, guitar-pro

For example in Sibelius I can control the lowest and highest frets I would like to be used when converting standard notation to tab. There doesn't seem to be anything like that in guitar pro. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of, you'd need a lot of rules to be added and it'd be a mess every time you wanted to import something.
What you can do, however, is [quickly move what string a note is on by using SHIFT  + ARROW UP/DOWN](https://www.reddit.com/r/GuitarPro/comments/bauqj0/easiest_way_to_change_fretstring_keeping_the_notes/). Works on GP6 7 8 and probably 5 too.

Comment: On Mac, the command is "OPTION + ARROW" (SHIFT just highlights the note).